# Not able to uplaod htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to upload my new website (codeigniter project) to the server. .htaccess file is used in my project and it is working properly in localhost. Also, i can upload the file too, but after uploading, it is not working. I always need to add the 'index.php' in  url. I can't see the .htaccess file and when i trying to upload it again, it is showing the message, the file is alredy exist. Do anyone know the reason?

Comment: This is something you'll need to solve with your webhost.

Comment: You can't see it because in Linux the leading DOT means this is a hidden file.

Comment: Maybe the server runs Nginx instead of Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using FileZilla and enable hidden files to be visible:

1. Open FileZilla FTP client.
2. From the Menu bar choose Server
3. Select Force Showing Hidden Files which should be the last option.

[image]

One other thing to check is if you're using Apache or Nginx because Nginx does not support the .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

I am using winSCP(FTP software) to upload my .htaccess. As you mentioned you are not able to view it. However when you try to create a new file through winScp, the file will be automatically loaded to your text editor.

I am not sure if other FTP software works the same.

Answer (score 0):

The file exists, but is hidden.

Probably the user on whose log does not have permission to replace him.

Answer (score 0):

remove .htaccess file from your server , but before make sure that that file is no more useful for you .

other way

open the hosting server .htaccess file in online editor of cpanel
now copy past your htaccess file codes which required to be change.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it could be that the server is running for example Nginx instead of Apache.

However, I think the most likely cause for the `.htaccess` file not having an effect is a configuration issue. It could be that `.htaccess` functionality is disabled either in config you can manage, or in the server's config.

Contact your webhost to resolve this issue.